# How to create human-readable identifier with more than 64 bits of entropy on IBM Netezza?

Tags: sql, hash, identifier, netezza, entropy

I'm working on IBM Netezza/PureData and I want to add an identifier column to a table containing billions of new records every day, so that I can track each record as it *travels* through different tables and systems. I want this identifier to have more than 64 bits of entropy, as the column may contain (in time) more than 10^12 different records, and I want to avoid hash collisions. According to [this table](http://opine.me/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/BirthdayAttack.png), 64 bits is not enough to avoid hash collisions with this number of records.

**Not enough bits**

So, on Netezza I can easily do

```
select hash8(123456) as id
```

which will return a 64-bit number (BIGINT):

```
-1789169473613552245
```

This is perfectly readable, but it has only 64-bits of entropy.

**Not human readable**

I can also do:

```
select hash(123456) as id
```

to create a 128-bit hash on Netezza. This has more than enough entropy, but it becomes an unreadable mess of unicode characters:

```
oð8^GþåíOpJ
```

I'm afraid this will cause trouble when I start combining this date with tables from other systems.

**Enough bits and human readable?**

So instead, I would like to create a human-readable identifier by, for example, converting this 128-bit unicode string to a base-62 string, containing only alphanumeric characters (0-9, a-z, A-Z). Something like:

```
6KMPOATg6Y5TbuEZlD59Dp
```

Any ideas on how to do this? Ideally with only (Netezza) SQL-code or functions...

Comment: You can't avoid hash collision, just reduce probability. Your approach sounds like hashing in Data Vault 2.0 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_vault_modeling), best case uses a well-known hashing algorithm which is availabe on different system (or can easily be ported).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to have the SQL extensions available (hash() being one of the Netezza SQL extension functions), you could try doing 'rawtohex()' on the output of your hash()

e.g.

```
select rawtohex(hash(123456));
```

This gives a nice HEX string representation of the hashed data:

```
'E10ADC3949BA59ABBE56E057F20F883E'
```

Comment: Thanks, Finbarr. Seems like a decent solution for now! My only gripe with this one, is that the strings remain quite long because it only uses 16 different characters. Granted, I didn't mention that I would like to keep it short ;).

Comment: On the other hand, even with Base 62 encoding, you'd still need about 22 characters instead of the 32 you get with your solution. So, 32 bytes isn't that bad really.

Comment: Yeah I did understand the desire for base 62, for that you would probably need to go down the route of creating your own UDF (user defined function) C++ module and create a netezza function to reference this. A good starting point is the IBM knowledge center docs, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.udf.doc/c_udf_plg_overview.html

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL has base-64 support, in XML datatype.

```
declare @source varbinary(max), @encoded varchar(max), @decoded varbinary(max)
set @source = convert(varbinary(max), 'Hello Base64')
set @encoded = cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@source"))', 'varchar(max)')
set @decoded = cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@encoded"))', 'varbinary(max)')
select
convert(varchar(max), @source) as source_varchar,
@source as source_binary,
@encoded as encoded,
@decoded as decoded_binary,
convert(varchar(max), @decoded) as decoded_varchar
```

From http://blog.falafel.com/t-sql-easy-base64-encoding-and-decoding/

Comment: Thanks for your time, Serg. I'm not exactly an engineer though. How would I go about implementing the code above? I'm not familiar with the kind of code you posted.

Comment: I'm not Netezza man, my guess was it may have an  XML datatype and supporting XQuery library too as MS SQL  have.